# Writing Hibernate queries in JSP gives java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, hibernate, jsp, spring-mvc, nullpointerexception

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>WebSLCM</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>/WEB-INF/resources/jsp/index.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>spring-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
      <param-value>/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/WEB-INF/resources/jsp/404.jsp</location>
  </error-page>
</web-app>
```

**dispatcher-servlet.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
        xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
        xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
             http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
             http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
             http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd 
             http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
             http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
             http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
             http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
             http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop 
             http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd">

    <mvc:annotation-driven />
    <!-- <mvc:default-servlet-handler/> -->
    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="WEB-INF/resources/" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.slv.controller" />

    <!-- JDBC Properties -->
    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/webslcm" />
        <property name="username" value="root" />
        <property name="password" value="root" />
    </bean>

    <!-- Accounts -->
    <bean id="accountsDaoImpl" class="com.slv.daoimpl.AccountsDaoImpl">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>

    <!-- Hibernate Session properties -->
    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.slv.model" />
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <!-- ViewResolver Spring Will redirecting -->
    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/resources/jsp/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>
```

**Jsp Page:**

```
<%!
    @Autowired
    public AccountsDaoImpl accountsDaoImpl;
%>
<% 
    List<Object[]> list =  accountsDaoImpl.getSQLObjectValues("SELECT examId, examName FROM examtypes", session);
%>
```

When i run the above code in JSP, im getting `java.lang.NullPointerException` Exception.

Not able resolve it, did i missed anything important? What changes should i make to my code to get worked?

**AccountsDaoImpl.java**

```
public class AccountsDaoImpl implements AccountsDao{

@Autowired
    public SessionFactory sessionFactory;

public SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
    return sessionFactory;
}

public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
    this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
}

@Override
    public List<Object[]> getSQLObjectValues(String sqlQuery, HttpSession session2) {
        Session session=sessionFactory.openSession(); // Here im getting the below exception 
        session.beginTransaction();
        try{
            Query query = session.createSQLQuery(sqlQuery);
            List<Object[]> list=query.list();
            return list;
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally{
            session.close();sessionFactory.close();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

**Exception:**

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.slv.daoimpl.AccountsDaoImpl.getSQLObjectValues(AccountsDaoImpl.java:384)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.resources.jsp.reUsableReport_jsp._jspService(reUsableReport_jsp.java:179)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:749)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:487)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:412)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:339)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:168)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:303)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1244)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1027)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:971)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: why you calling queries in jsp?

Comment: above code is just a sample example, there is lot of queries to be run. Its not possible for to write queries in Controller and get back to JSP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To enable auto-wiring in JSP, you must enable it by the help of **SpringBeanAutowiringSupport** by overriding **jspInit()** function.

So, the modified **jsp Page** as follows:

```
<%@ page import="org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired"%>
<%@ page import="org.springframework.web.context.support.SpringBeanAutowiringSupport"%>

<%!
    public void jspInit() {
      SpringBeanAutowiringSupport.processInjectionBasedOnServletContext(this,getServletConfig().getServletContext());
    } 

    @Autowired
    public AccountsDaoImpl accountsDaoImpl;
%>
<% 
    List<Object[]> list =  accountsDaoImpl.getSQLObjectValues("SELECT examId, examName FROM examtypes", session);
%>
```

**dispatcher-servlet.xml:**

You also have to add bean for **AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor**
:
`<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor"/>`

So, Modified version:

```
 <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
        xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
        xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
             http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
             http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
             http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd 
             http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
             http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
             http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
             http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
             http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop 
             http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd">

    <mvc:annotation-driven />
    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="WEB-INF/resources/" />
   <context:component-scan base-package="com.slv.controller" />
  <!--   Write Hibernate queries in JSP -->
   <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor"/> 

    <!-- JDBC Properties -->
    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/webslcm" />
        <property name="username" value="root" />
        <property name="password" value="root" />
    </bean>

    <!-- Accounts -->
    <bean id="accountsDaoImpl" class="com.slv.daoimpl.AccountsDaoImpl">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>

    <!-- Hibernate Session properties -->
    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.slv.model" />
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <!-- ViewResolver Spring Will redirecting -->
    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/resources/jsp/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

**web.xml:**

You have to add **context-param** and listener:**org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener** in **web.xml**

Modified:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>WebSLCM</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>/WEB-INF/resources/jsp/index.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
    <!-- The definition of the Root Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
</context-param>    

<!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>spring-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
      <param-value>/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/WEB-INF/resources/jsp/404.jsp</location>
  </error-page>
</web-app>
```

Comment: i tried above code, its showing below error at browser

Comment: HTTP Status 500 - java.lang.IllegalStateException: No WebApplicationContext found: no ContextLoaderListener registered?

Comment: i updated web.xml,, its showing HTTP Status 404 - /WebSLCM/index when i run the application

Comment: check **/WEB-INF/resources/jsp/index.jsp** exist?

Comment: 404!! So, your welcome file may not exist in **/WEB-INF/resources/jsp/index.jsp**. if **welcome-file** do exists, you could share the console error stackstrace so that i can assist to pin point the mistake.

Comment: if if welcome-file do exists, I guess you have to add **@Service** anotation to **AccountsDaoImpl** to remove 404 error.

Comment: if you still have errors, add **log4j.properties** and run the project, share the error console.

Comment: your answer worked for me but i want to make some changes in your above answer as i made.. can i ?

Comment: didn't approved the changes?

Comment: ok.. i will select your answer as correct answer.. thank you buddy

Answer (score 3):

You are not using the Spring context to generate the bean for you, basically ignoring all your Spring configuration. You could look the bean up from the application content in the JSP, but **writing application code in JSP is always a bad idea!** That's why I won't give a more detailed answer, don't shoot yourself in the foot on purpose. Autowire the bean in a servlet, and invoke it through a request in the JSP.

#### Autowiring in a servlet

You can use the `SpringBeanAutowiringSupport` utility class, to inject your spring beans:

```
public class MyServlet implements HttpServlet {

    @Autowired
    private MyBean myBean;

    public void init(ServletConfig config) {
        super.init(config);
        SpringBeanAutowiringSupport.processInjectionBasedOnServletContext(this);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it would be best to make the sql call in the service layer and populate a form backing object in the controller and then send the list of objects back to the JSP to be displayed. Is there a reason why the SQL calls need to be made in the JSP?

Comment: above code is just a sample example, there is lot of queries to be run. Its not possible for to write queries in Controller and get back to JSP

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this

```
AccountsDaoImpl accountsDaoImpl = new AccountsDaoImpl();
```

You need to get `accountsDaoImpl` from a Spring context to have

```
@Autowired
public SessionFactory sessionFactory;
```

is auto wired by Spring.

Comment: How can i add that to my JSP page?

Comment: You cannot inject in JSP. So try to do it in servlet from where you would be coming here and save the query result in request . and that you can retrieve here.

Comment: @KulbhushanSingh do you have any sample example?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use setter of the sessionfactory.

```
protected HibernateTemplate template = null;

/**
 * Sets Hibernate session factory and creates a 
 * <code>HibernateTemplate</code> from it.
 */
public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
    template = new HibernateTemplate(sessionFactory);
}
```

Comment: Try Session session=getSessionFactory().openSession();

Comment: Also check case of variable. upper case or lowercase.

Answer (score 0):

I see that you have mixed annotation driven and non-annotation driven styles. Try:

1. Removing the `accountsDaoImpl` bean definition from your spring config xml
2. Either removing the setter method `setSessionFactory` from your `AccountsDaoImpl` or moving the Autowired annotation from the `sessionFactory` instance variable to the the `setSessionFactory` method. I think either will do but you have both which is contributing to your problem.

Comment: Thank you but anyway i got the answer from @Md. Minhajur Rahman